# Drone CI/CD - container cannot find .NET SDKs

Tags: c#, .net, docker, drone.io

I'm using .NET Core 3.1. using drone to do C/D.

My .drone.yml is

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: deployment

steps:
- name: build
  image: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/yoyosoft/dotnet/core/sdk
  commands:
    - dotnet restore src/YOGA.Api
    - dotnet restore src/YOGA.MIniProgram.API
    - dotnet publish  src/YOGA.Api --framework netcoreapp3.1 --configuration Release --output src/YOGA.Api/dist
    - dotnet publish  src/YOGA.MIniProgram.API --framework netcoreapp3.1 --configuration Release --output src/YOGA.MIniProgram.API/dist
    - echo "$(pwd)"
    - ls
    - cd src
    - ls
    - cd YOGA.Api
    - ls 
     
- name: YOGA.Api to AliyunHub
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    dockerfile: src/YOGA.Api/Dockerfile
    tags: latest
    insecure: true
    registry: "registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com"
    repo: "registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mrt_backend_api/mrt_backend_api"
    username:
      from_secret: username
    password:
      from_secret: userpassword
- name: YOGA.Mini to AliyunHub
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    dockerfile: src/YOGA.MIniProgram.API/Dockerfile
    tags: latest
    insecure: true
    registry: "registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com"
    repo: "registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mini_mrt_backend_api"
    username:
      from_secret: username
    password:
      from_secret: userpassword     
- name: deploy
  image: appleboy/drone-ssh
  pull: true
  settings:
    host: ...
    port: ...
    username: ...
    password: ...
    script:
      - echo start deploy- echo pulling images from  AliyunHub 
      - docker login --username=...registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com --password=...
      - docker pull docker pull registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mini_mrt_backend_api:latest
      - docker tag registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mini_mrt_backend_api:latest mini-mrt-api:latest
      - docker run --name mrt-mini-api -d -p xxx:80 mini-mrt-api
      - docker pull registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mrt_backend_api:latest
      - docker tag registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/yoga_images/mrt_backend_api:latest mrt-api:latest
      - docker run --name mrt-api -d -p xxx:5000 mrt-api
```

Drone works fine.
Here is my dockerfile which looks similar...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

RUN echo "PWD is: $PWD"

COPY src/YOGA.Api/dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","YOGA.Api.dll"]
```

Here's the output from the the ls command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW4uN.png)

Everything looks fine.

After drone finishes, the container does not start up,

Here's the error from the docker logs...

```
docker logs 57c728d627cd
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Anyone know the solution?

thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works

i'm pushing to my repository has failed.